Fine-grained permissions in GIT
I would like to use a single GIT repository with fine-grained access control, ie. at branch/tag/directory/file level for read and write accesses.
As far as I know, GIT has a build-in mechanism of hooks that can be used to implement access control into pre-hooks called on commits but there is no pre-hook for checkout and clone. Moreover, gitolite provides fine-grained access control for write access but not for read access.
I would like to avoid having to use one repository per role as there won't be only two or three roles. Am I missing something obvious?
P.S: In order to avoid any confusion, please note that I don't use Microsoft-owned Github and similar solutions, I have my own server at home. git != github

Write is simple: use CODEOWNERS and create branch protection rules to enforce reviews from the code owners for incoming PRs.
But for READ access too? Don't think that's possible. Git assumes a commit is an atomic object and you get all that information. You could use submodules to aggregate multiple repositories with different access rules into one big one, but that could also be annoying if updating submodules regularly shows error messages.

Thank you for your answer. Sorry for the confusion, maybe I should have been more accurate because GIT != github. For the read access, yes it's the tricky part. Ok, I'm going to edit my question.

@gouessej "Server at home" - what do you need fine-grained access control for, are other people involved in whatever you are doing on your home server?

It's for a kind of content management system engine, I must have read and write access everywhere in the repository, unauthenticated users must have read-only access on the public part of the project, the person whose role consists in copying the contents elsewhere in case of troubles must have read-only access everywhere, some contributors must have read and write access on a subset of the repository. I'm currently checking whether I could do that with submodules. If so, I'll obviously accept your answer.
